# Как написать кириллицу на картинку с помощью imagestring

Tags: php, кириллица, gd

Я пробовал с помощью, но безуспешно.

```php
iconv("WINDOWS-1251","UTF-8","Русяшный текст");
```

И юникод также не работает.

```
\u0420\u0443\u0441\u044f\u0448\u043d\u044b\u0439\u0020\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php), imagestring поддерживает только latin2(ну или кастомные шрифты, загруженные с [imageloadfont](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imageloadfont.php))

Comment: В imagetfftext проблема с подключением шрифтов (он их не находит)

Comment: [Задавайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)